# Are there is any available meteor whatsapp share packages?

Tags: meteor, whatsapp, meteor-packages

Am developing an app using the meteor framework. 
I have been able to add social sharing functions/buttons to enable sharing via facebook, twitter and googleplus.

I would now like to add a share via Whatsapp button/function. 
I have searched on atmospherejs.com but cant seem to find any whatsapp share packages.

Can anyone point me to a proven Whatsapp share package?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the npm package [whatsapp-sharing](https://www.npmjs.com/package/whatsapp-sharing)